# Magento2 Back End is working fine but front end is not working and showing This page isn’t working error

Tags: magento, magento2

I am working on a magento project. it was working fine till today.but today when i open it its not working and following error is coming in error log

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection::addIsSaleableAttributeToFilter() must be of the type array or null, integer given, called in /home/olfwmbaph2hf/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php on line 1582 and defined in /home/olfwmbaph2hf/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php:2475
```

Stack trace:

## 0 /home/olfwmbaph2hf/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php(1582): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection->addIsSaleableAttributeToFilter(1)

## 1 /home/olfwmbaph2hf/public_html/app/code/Smartwave/Filterproducts/Block/Home/LatestList.php(56): Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left')

## 2 /home/olfwmbaph2hf/public_html/app/code/Smartwave/Filterproducts/Block/Home/LatestList.php(33): Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\Home\LatestList->getProducts()

## 3 /home/olfw in /home/olfwmbaph2hf/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php on line 2475

can some please help to remove this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try following solution mentioned here [Error after indexing after upgrade to 2.3.3](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Error-after-indexing-after-upgrade-to-2-3-3/m-p/144563#M11172)

> I am getting this too after upgrading! However, if I change the theme used (Content -> Design -> Config) I can successfully view my site!

```
Change the 1 (integer) into array
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', 1, 'left')
```

to this

```
addAttributeToFilter('is_saleable', [1], 'left')
```

in in /home/olfwmbaph2hf/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Collection.php on line 1582

Answer (score 0):

This is Porto theme issue with newer version so, better please installed porto theme patch from their support site and install it.

it will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you using Porto theme with Magento 2.3.3 you need to update the latest patch follow this link to see more detail [Check more detail on this website](https://magento2expert.com/error-after-indexing-after-upgrade-to-magento-2-3-3-porto-theme/)

Do not edit core files updating this patch will solve your issue !